# Nvidia driver with optimus

Tags: nvidia

It's possible to install nvidia drivers with a card graphic with optimus on my laptop or I can only install bumblebee-nvidia ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can used nvidia-driver on a latop with optimus.
Bumblebee-nvidia is for my case on a MSI GP62 6QF not a good solution, because my intel graphic is performance equal to my nvidia card with bumblebee-nvidia. And when i used with only nvidia-driver my card is so much better on LinuxMint